# Why does the schwa sounds like an 'e' in some words?

Tags: phonetics

I've noticed that in some words the schwa sounds more like 'e' and not 'ə',
for exmaple: environment(.mənt), is with a schwa, but sounds like 'e'.
Also in a word like 'substance'-stance doesn't sound like it has a schwa but it has.

Comment: English doesn't have a vowel letter that maps mainly to schwa (they all can in some words), so your question feels like it's back to front. Apart from accent, stress patterns aren't set in stone and stressing a vowel that's normally a schwa will change it.

Comment: I suspect you're hearing features of specific accents; for example, I often hear the last vowel in 'environment' as /ɪ/ instead of /ə/, as in the word "mint".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it fails to appreciate that the schwa is not present in some of the pronunciations it mentions.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing different accents. In my normal speech (Southeast England) "-ment" has a schwa. In my adopted speech (Yorkshire) it often has an [ɛ] sound.

Comment: So what is the correct and most common way to pronounce it?

Comment: @artde: unanswerable. Depends which dialect (or group of dialects).

Comment: @artde I don't think you understand what a schwa denotes. The whole purpose of a schwa is to be a placeholder for an unspecified sound. It is not pronounced in a specific way. You cannot specify an unspecified sound. As soon as you can, you just use the specific symbol for that specific sound. A schwa might well be an /e/, or an /ɛ/, or an /ɜ/, or any sound at all close to that position, or indeed no sound at all, depending on the context and the speaker and the phase of the moon.

Comment: @RegDwigнt schwa unspecified sound? where can I check this?

Comment: Not so, @RegDwigнt. The OED says "The central vowel sound /ə/, typically occurring in weakly stressed syllables, as in the final syllable of ‘sofa’ and the first syllable of ‘along’", and that is certainly my understanding of the term: a specific sound, not an unspecified one. Artde's use of the word is normal.

Comment: @ColinFine so why is my use of the word normal? I was sure that I'm wrong, because I pronounce it with a short /e/ and not /ə/

Comment: @artde: yes; in your dialect/accent that word does not have a schwa in it.

Comment: @ColinFine My accent could be wrong, I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: @artde: I think you may be misunderstanding me. When I said your use of the word was normal, I meant that you used the word "schwa" to refer to a specific vowel - I was disagreeing with Reg about the meaning of the word "schwa".. As for your pronunciation of English words, it depends what accent you have been taught or are striving for. As I say, I pronounce "-ment" differently depending on which accent I'm using, which in turn depends on where I am, who I'm talking to, the social setting, and other factors. If you aspire to an accent which uses /ə/, then you should use  /ə/.

Comment: @ColinFine I'm familiar mostly with the American accent and the American dictionaries show '-ment' with a schwa, may be I am wrong, but I think that 
 Americans pronounce it with an 'e'.

Comment: @artde: [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_English) lists eleven main regional US accents. I'm pretty sure they don't all use a schwa in "-ment".